# Using Copyright symbol in code section

Tags: inno-setup

I am using inno setup to build a setup kit. I have a special requirement where I need to insert a string value into the registry with copyright symbol. I am using following code to insert the string in `[Code]` section.

```
RegWriteStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Station', 'CopyRightText', '(C) Copyright My Company Limited, 2014');
```

In place of `(C)` I would like to insert the actual `copyright symbol`. How can I achieve this?

Update: I am using Inno setup version 5.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is `#169` :-)

```
RegWriteStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Station', 'CopyRightText', #169 + 'Copyright My Company Limited, 2014');
```

[Full table of codes](http://entitycode.com/)

Comment: For those using ISO 8859-1 charset or one of its subsets, you can store the © character directly in the script without escaping since it is stored in the upper range of ISO 8859-1 chars which was mapped the same way by the Latin-1 Unicode Supplement. Escaping this char makes the script less readable.