# How to get the actual Copyright symbol in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, symbols

In an Inno Setup (Unicode) script, I'd like to define the copyright text using the actual copyright symbol (The letter C in a circle). This is in the `[Setup]` section as `AppCopyright`.

How do I insert the actual copyright symbol here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Copyright symbol in code section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161698/using-copyright-symbol-in-code-section). But I don't like the answer there. There's no need to escape the © char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the InnoIDE or a text editor, type `Copyright`, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and type  <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>, then release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.